# Proper time interval between two pulses of a laser

Tags: general-relativity

If I have a laser that emits with frequency $v_0$, what is the proper time interval between two pulses when I get to a radius $R$ from $\infty$ to a star of mass $M$?

The proper time difference between two consecutive pulses would be $\dfrac{\sqrt{g_{00}(R)}}{v_0}$, since $dt = 1/v_0$.

But proper time interval is supposed to be invariant under general co-ordinate transformations and $\sqrt{g_{00}(R)}$ would not be.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** reframed the question

Comment: What is the difference between *experiencing* and *measuring*?

Comment: I believe [Wikipedia page on Gravitational Redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift) does address your issue.

Comment: The [Pound-Reba-Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound–Rebka_experiment) shows that we are able to detect curvature of space time even on different high on earth.

Comment: @sammygerbil 

Edited:- Reframed the question. I realized I was pretty vague earlier.

Comment: @StephenG 

Edited:- Reframed the question. I realized I was pretty vague earlier.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler 
Edited:- Reframed the question. I realized I was pretty vague earlier.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Do you mean you, the observer, fire the two pulses from infinity towards the mass and you want to know the proper distance between the two pulses as they travel towards the mass? Or do you mean you carry the laser to a distance $R$ from the mass then fire two pulses?

Comment: @JohnRennie I am standing at a distance $R$ from the mass, and then I measure the frequency in my local frame. The frequency $v_0$ is what I had measured standing at the same point but in absence of the mass.

Comment: @Cheeku: you measure the frequency to $\nu_0$ in both cases of course. An external observer at infinity would observe the frequency of your laser to be red shifted, but you would not.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking. Are you asking for the proper time difference between the spacetime points when the two pulses leave your laser i.e. in your rest frame just the elapsed time, or are you asking about the proper distance between the pulses at some specified time e.g. the proper distance to the first pulse at the moment the second pulse leaves the laser?

Comment: @JohnRennie Proper time difference between the spacetime points when the two pulses leave my laser. These spacetime points are just 'time' points as the laser is stationary and the wavelength is very small as compared to the scale at which the metric changes.

Comment: @Cheeku: I have answered, but the answer is so simple that I can't help feeling I have missed some subtlety in what you are asking.

Comment: @JohnRennie I think you have missed something. Even I had figured the answer is simple, but a student in my GTR class raised some arguments against this. This discussion took 2 lectures of heated debate between the professor and the student.

I don't think I have been very clear on what I mean either. We should take this over to some chat session.

Answer (score 1):

Under general coordinate transformations the radius $R$ may not be the appropriate coordinate to mark the position of laser device. And, most importantly, what is the physical meaning of frequency $\nu_0$? We can speculate that your $\nu_0$ is measured in the laser device relative rest local inertial reference frame at radius $R$ of the spacetime. But under a general coordinate transformation, the laser device will no longer be at rest in the new coordinate and the frequency of laser $\nu_0$ will also change accordingly. In short, after coordinate transformations, generally,
$$\nu'_0\neq \nu_0,\quad R'\neq R,\quad \frac{\sqrt{g_{00}}}{\nu_0}=\Delta\tau=\Delta\tau'\neq\frac{\sqrt{g'_{0'0'}}}{\nu'_0}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We'll suppose you are sitting a distance $r$ from the mass, and you are holding your laser. As measured in your frame the frequency of the laser is $v_0$, so the time between two crests of the light wave it emits is $t=1/v_0$. Since you and the laser are stationary in your rest frame the proper time between two crests of the light wave is therefore just:

$$ \tau = \frac{1}{\nu_0} \tag{1} $$

Now suppose I am far (effectively at an infinite distance) from the black hole observing you. From my perspective your laser has been gravitationally red shifted to a frequency:

$$ \nu' = \nu_0\sqrt{g_{00}(r)} $$

So the coordinate time I measure between crests of the wave is:

$$ t = \frac{1}{\nu_0\sqrt{g_{00}(r)}} \tag{2} $$

To calculate the proper time that corresponds to my measured coordinate time I use the metric, and since there is no movement in space the metric simplifies to:

$$ c^2d\tau^2 = g_{00}c^2dt^2 $$

Substituting in my value for $t$ from equation (2) I get:

$$ \tau = \sqrt{g_{00}}\,\frac{1}{\nu_0\sqrt{g_{00}(r)}} = \frac{1}{\nu_0} $$

So both you and I obtain the same value for the proper time.

Comment: Our clock's measure proper time right?

Comment: @Cheeku: a clock at your location and stationary with respect to you measures your proper time. If the clock is moving relative to you or if it is not at the same point in space as you then it will not measure your proper time.

Comment: @Cheeku: I wonder if it's the derivation of equation (1) that is bothering you i.e. why equation (1) gives the proper time while equation (2) gives the coordinate time?